# Angular передать данные на сервер

Tags: angular

Необходимо передать на php сервер  email чтобы выбрать из БД пользователя по mail, как в файле php принять данные для выборки??

в константу body попадает почта, а в если проверяю массив $_POST в PHP файле он пустой почему то, может я что то не так понял?

```
getUserByMail(email: string){

    const body = {email: email};
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post('http://ng-everyday/php/test.php', body);

  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485690/10123947

Comment: Спасибо. Там есть полезная инфа